# ghc-pkg: cannot find package ghc-7.10.2.20150906

Tags: haskell, ghc

I need to expose a package ghc-7.10.2.20150906. 
When I use "ghc-pkg list", I see this:[image]

But when I'm trying to expose ghc-7.10.2.20150906 by `sudo ghc-pkg expose ghc-7.10.2.20150906`, I get a message:

> ghc-pkg: cannot find package ghc-7.10.2.20150906

What's the problem? Or is there another way to expose it?

Cabal file:

```
-- This is the configuration file for the 'cabal' command line tool.

-- The available configuration options are listed below.
-- Some of them have default values listed.

-- Lines (like this one) beginning with '--' are comments.
-- Be careful with spaces and indentation because they are
-- used to indicate layout for nested sections.


remote-repo: hackage.haskell.org:http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive
remote-repo-cache: /home/valoisa/.cabal/packages
-- local-repo:
-- logs-dir:
world-file: /home/valoisa/.cabal/world
-- verbose: 1
-- compiler: ghc
-- with-compiler:
-- with-hc-pkg:
-- scratchdir:
-- program-prefix: 
-- program-suffix: 
-- library-vanilla: True
-- library-profiling: False
-- shared:
-- executable-dynamic: False
-- executable-profiling: False
-- optimization: True
-- library-for-ghci: False
-- split-objs: False
-- executable-stripping: True
-- user-install: True
-- package-db:
-- flags:
-- extra-include-dirs:
-- extra-lib-dirs:
extra-prog-path: /home/valoisa/.cabal/bin
-- tests: False
-- library-coverage: False
-- benchmarks: False
-- cabal-lib-version:
-- constraint:
-- preference:
-- solver: choose
-- documentation: False
-- doc-index-file: $datadir/doc/index.html
-- max-backjumps: 2000
-- reorder-goals: False
-- shadow-installed-packages: False
-- strong-flags: False
-- reinstall: False
-- avoid-reinstalls: False
-- force-reinstalls: False
-- upgrade-dependencies: False
-- root-cmd:
-- symlink-bindir:
build-summary: /home/valoisa/.cabal/logs/build.log
-- build-log:
remote-build-reporting: anonymous
-- one-shot: False
jobs: $ncpus
-- username:
-- password:

install-dirs user
  -- prefix: /home/valoisa/.cabal
  -- bindir: $prefix/bin
  -- libdir: $prefix/lib
  -- libsubdir: $arch-$os-$compiler/$pkgid
  -- libexecdir: $prefix/libexec
  -- datadir: $prefix/share
  -- datasubdir: $arch-$os-$compiler/$pkgid
  -- docdir: $datadir/doc/$arch-$os-$compiler/$pkgid
  -- htmldir: $docdir/html
  -- haddockdir: $htmldir
  -- sysconfdir: $prefix/etc

install-dirs global
  -- prefix: /usr/local
  -- bindir: $prefix/bin
  -- libdir: $prefix/lib
  -- libsubdir: $arch-$os-$compiler/$pkgid
  -- libexecdir: $prefix/libexec
  -- datadir: $prefix/share
  -- datasubdir: $arch-$os-$compiler/$pkgid
  -- docdir: $datadir/doc/$arch-$os-$compiler/$pkgid
  -- htmldir: $docdir/html
  -- haddockdir: $htmldir
  -- sysconfdir: $prefix/etc

program-locations 
  -- alex-location:
  -- ar-location:
  -- c2hs-location:
  -- cpphs-location:
  -- ffihugs-location:
  -- gcc-location:
  -- ghc-location:
  -- ghc-pkg-location:
  -- greencard-location:
  -- haddock-location:
  -- happy-location:
  -- hmake-location:
  -- hpc-location:
  -- hsc2hs-location:
  -- hscolour-location:
  -- hugs-location:
  -- jhc-location:
  -- ld-location:
  -- lhc-location:
  -- lhc-pkg-location:
  -- nhc98-location:
  -- pkg-config-location:
  -- ranlib-location:
  -- strip-location:
  -- tar-location:
  -- uhc-location:

program-default-options 
  -- alex-options:
  -- ar-options:
  -- c2hs-options:
  -- cpphs-options:
  -- ffihugs-options:
  -- gcc-options:
  -- ghc-options:
  -- ghc-pkg-options:
  -- greencard-options:
  -- haddock-options:
  -- happy-options:
  -- hmake-options:
  -- hpc-options:
  -- hsc2hs-options:
  -- hscolour-options:
  -- hugs-options:
  -- jhc-options:
  -- ld-options:
  -- lhc-options:
  -- lhc-pkg-options:
  -- nhc98-options:
  -- pkg-config-options:
  -- ranlib-options:
  -- strip-options:
  -- tar-options:
  -- uhc-options:
```

Comment: Please post the command you used to compile and any output from that command. Are you using cabal? If so, please post the cabal file. If you're not using cabal you probably should be.

Comment: `ghc-7.10.20150906` is not `ghc-7.10.2.20150906`.

Comment: Also, you can just use `ghc-pkg expose ghc`.

Comment: @ReidBarton Oh, exсuse me, it was a typo.

Comment: @GarethR Thanks for your response, I've posted a cabal file.

Comment: Using `ghc-pkg expose ghc` didn't help :(

Comment: Could you share the output of `sudo ghc-pkg -v2 expose ghc` ?

Comment: Didn't help with what? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @ReidBarton I want to use some modules from GHC API, in particular I want to be able to import them in ghci.

Comment: @adamse [here it is](http://freetexthost.com/d1utxlrsoa)

Comment: @O.Phillips: any success?

Comment: @adamse Yes, the problem was that root used the wrong `ghc-pkg`. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you're writing a larger Haskell project you would specify the packages that you want to use in a project specific Cabal file, here is a quite minimal example that uses the `base` package and the `ghc` package, `example.cabal`:

```
name:                example
version:             0.1.0.0
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10

library
  exposed-modules:     AModule
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                       , ghc
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

To use the GHC 7.10.3 snapshot with this project you run `cabal configure --with-compiler=PATH/TO/ghc-7.10.3`, then you can access your project with the dependent packages in a GHCi session using `cabal repl`.

---

If you really want to expose the `ghc` package your problem seems to be that the `sudo ghc-pkg` invocation is not the ghc-pkg from the 7.10.3 snapshot, as evidenced by the line

> flag db stack: ["/home/valoisa/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.10.2/package.conf.d","/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.10.2/package.conf.d"]

in the [output](http://freetexthost.com/d1utxlrsoa) of `sudo ghc-pkg -v2 expose ghc` you posted.

I can see two possible solutions

1. Don't use `sudo` as it seems the correct version of `ghc-pkg` is used (I can't think of any reason to use sudo here).
2. Use the correct `ghc-pkg` by specifying the whole path to the program.

Comment: Good catch on the different version of GHC being used under sudo! An easy way to be sure to use the same version is `sudo $(which ghc-pkg) expose ghc`.